# reference to a dll can't be found or removed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

After refactoring a WCF service, the service throws an error saying that it can't find a library that it's no longer supposed to use. The reference to the DLL has been removed from the projects' references, it's not in the config files, and looking through the XML of the `.csproj` files, there's no artifact reference. The solution has also been cleaned and rebuilt multiple times, the IIS server on which it's running has been restarted, its app pool recycled, and I even found the `.cache` files in the Debug folder and yet, the app is still complaining that it can't find the DLL it's no longer supposed to use.

Where else could a reference possibly be hiding and what can I do not to have to re-assemble the service file by file, project by project, or calling some sort of .NET exorcist to ensure that the offending DLL isn't there anymore?

Comment: Try to remove bin and object folders, but close the IDE firstly also just in case remove .suo file. Then rebuilt it again

Comment: Maybe another referenced component still uses it?

Comment: Use **fuslogvw.exe** tool which will shows you from which place the project trying to refer the dll at runtime

Comment: @Anton wins it. Removing the .suo file didn't do anything, neither did the `fusloqvw.exe` utility, but removing both the `bin` and `obj` folders worked. I'm not sure how or where this reference was held, or why they both had to be removed for it to work, not just one or the other, but it was successfully exorcised. Thanks!

Comment: @user1446184 you must have had a lingering DLL with a reference to it